# Set LifeCycle Management Rule on all blobs in a container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, lifecycle

I am trying to set a rule which will delete all blobs in a container if they have not been modified for x number of days. I am following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal#rules)

The issue is, I am not able to find a rule which will work for all blobs in a specific container. I tried using `container/` and `container/*` but to no effect.

Can someone guide how to achieve this? Thanks

Output of `Get-AzStorageAccountManagementPolicy`

> PS C:\windows\system32> Get-AzStorageAccountManagementPolicy -ResourceGroupName “” -StorageAccountName “”
>
> ResourceGroupName  : “” StorageAccountName : “” Id                 :
> /subscriptions/ddd
> /resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storaccount/managementPolicies
> /default Type               : Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/managementPolicies LastModifiedTime
> : 1/5/2021 10:54:21 AM Rules              : [
> {
> "Enabled":  true,
> "Name":  "allblobs",
> "Definition":  {
> "Actions":  {
> "BaseBlob":  {
> "TierToCool":  null,
> "TierToArchive":  null,
> "Delete":  {
> "DaysAfterModificationGreaterThan":  1
> }
> },
> "Snapshot":  null
> },
> "Filters":  {
> "PrefixMatch":  [
> "cont1/"
> ],
> "BlobTypes":  [
> "blockBlob"
> ]
> }
> }
> }
> ]

Comment: The platform runs the lifecycle policy once a day. Once you configure a policy, it can take up to 24 hours for some actions to run for the first time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I noticed this but nothing happened even after a week when I set the blob to delete if it has not been modified for 2 days. Could you tell me what should be the correct syntax for all blobs under a container?

Comment: if so, can you post the output of Get-AzStorageAccountManagementPolicy ?

Comment: For example : https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container1/foo/... for a rule, the prefixMatch is container1/foo.

Comment: Added the output. Yes it is container1/foo but I want to take action on all blobs inside container 1

Comment: when rule runs than its calculating some extra cost in billing or its free ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to delete all blobs in a container, then in the policy -> Filter set, `just specify the container name only`. For example, if the container name is `container1`, just set the Filter set as below:

[image]

Please also note that it may take effect after 24 hours. I did this settings before, and it worked well.

Comment: thank you for your reply! I will test this and get back to you

Comment: Hello Ivan, I set the rule and waited for 24 hours but nothing happened. The structure in my case is container1/folder1/folder2/files. Basically container 1 has many folders and they in turn have many files inside them. I want to delete everything inside container 1 which has not been modified for 1 day (lets say).

Comment: @Garima, are you using `storage account v2` or `data lake storage gen2`? Are you setting the policy via UI in azure portal? Please also make sure there're files not been modified for xx day you specified in the rule.

Comment: I was using storage account v2 and using UI. Over the weekend, I noticed that the files were deleted. It just took more than 24 hours to process the rule. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: is 'Life cycle management rule' when run some extra cost as well or its free?